# Duvida sobre Apis do Python

Tags: python-3.x

Bom dia!

Estou precisando de fazer um programa que simula a operação de um "usuário", essas operações são tomadas com base em varias circunstancias, teria que enviar código via Terminal do Linux e cmd Windows e também observar campos de um sistema assistido que mostram alarmes (estes alarmes são mostrados em forma de imagens/gifs), gostaria de saber quais APIs atualmente existem para fazer tais tarefas.

Obs.: obter essas informações por conta do sistema assistido, e muitos casos quando tento acessar a memoria do mesmo ele acaba "bugando" e fechando.

O intuito 'e eu conseguir desenvolver um software que ajuda aos administradores da rede a ficarem menos tempo e receberem certas informações de maneira mais rápida e segura.

Obs.: pergunto de Linux/Windows, devido ao fato de o meu software ter que pegar informações de 2 sistemas operacionais diferentes e alimentar uma base de dados.

Comment: Sua pergunta parece bastante abrangente. Seria melhor detalhar mais o que você precisa dando exemplos da entrada que você vai ter e a saída que espera. Colocar o código que você já tentou implementar também ajuda entender o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, Python seria uma boa, pois funciona no Windows e no Linux perfeitamente.
 Quando você fala em (simula a operação de um "usuário") eu penso logo em automação, que você pode fazer utilizando a Lib:
 Pywinauto (https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
Com a o Pywinauto, você consegue monitorar a aplicação desejada, pegar valores da aplicação, automatizar tarefas de modo rápido e simples. Podendo até monitorar a o Gerenciador de Tarefas do Windows, podendo assim, por exemplo: Saber qual programa está consumindo mais memoria RAM e encerrá-lo. Bem legal né?

Pode ser feito com Python2 também, utilizando a Lib:
 Pyautogui(https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
Porém essa lib é bem limitada. Não recomendo.

Essas Libs são se automação com Python, já trabalhei com as duas e elas funcionam bem.
Para exibir os alertas podemos utilizar a Lib [(win32)](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/), exemplo bem simples:

```
import win32api

win32api.MessageBox(0, 'hello', 'title')
```

Para exibir no linux você pode utilizar a lib ([simple-monitor-alert](https://pypi.org/project/simple-monitor-alert/)).
Acho que tirei suas dúvidas, qualquer coisa pergunta ai que eu respondo.
=D

Comment: Era +- isso mesmo oque eu precisava, ajudou muito, teria como so me tirar uma ultima duvida?

Quando eu uso:
pyautogui.getWindows()

ele da a seguinte mensagem de erro:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/link/PycharmProjects/Golem_Bot/venv/include/home.py", line 6, in <module>
    lista = list(pyautogui.getWindows())
AttributeError: module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'getWindows'

sabe como resolver ou como eu posso validar a tela para poder utilizar as apis que vc me recomendou?

Comment: Claro.  Fala ai.

Comment: eu editei o comentário a cima...

Comment: Cara, esse exception pode estar acontecendo por n motivos, difícil saber assim com poucas informações, não sei qual versão do pyautogui vc está usando, se tem um setup.py, o que tem dentro dele, quais dependências? Qual versão do PIP? Está utilizando um ambiente virtual? O melhor para você é fazer outra pergunta passando todos os detalhes. Não esquece de dar o feedback. =D